# android- Find nearest location to my current place

Tags: java, android

I've some gps coordinate on my database.

I get my current location but I don't know how can I find the nearest location to me and  the distance between me and those point .

Could you help me to find the nearest locations and the distance between me and those points ?

Comment: calculate distance between current latitude and longitude and database latitude and longitude.Get the smallest distance that's the nearest from current location.

Answer (score 2):

Use this method to find distance between two points http://www.geodatasource.com/developers/java

```
private double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2, char unit) {
      double theta = lon1 - lon2;
      double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.sin(deg2rad(lat2)) + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));
      dist = Math.acos(dist);
      dist = rad2deg(dist);
      dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
      if (unit == "K") {
        dist = dist * 1.609344;
      } else if (unit == "N") {
        dist = dist * 0.8684;
        }
      return (dist);
    }

    private double deg2rad(double deg) {
      return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
    }

    system.println(distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "M") + " Miles\n");
    system.println(distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "K") + " Kilometers\n");
    system.println(distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "N") + " Nautical Miles\n");
```

Comment: just a fix,       dist = rad2deg(dist); should be       dist = deg2rad(dist);
and unit == 'K' , unit == 'N' with one quotation mark

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built in method `distanceBetween()` of the class `android.location.Location` to calculate the distance between two lat longs.

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float[]%29)

On the whole what you will need to do is, find the distance between your current location and all other points individually and then find out the smallest one.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please tell us what is mean by nearest location? Do you have lat-long of that location (Nearest location)?

If yes then you can use **distanceBetween()** method of Location class. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float[]%29

If No, then
Google has some API which gives you nearby places which is registered on Google like Malls, Airports and then you can find distances between you and other locations.

Please see below link for more details.

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/